# WxPython : Display problems (on a device context)

Tags: wxpython, device, gdi

After many hours searching the solution to my problem on the web, I'm still being stuck. Here is the displaying problem :

As a beginner in programming, I've done a graphic interface thanks to `WxPython`, to display some values for a text file, which works perfectly with the classic version of `WxPython`.

Exactly the same code in Phoenix resulting a "flatten" graph in y direction within few pixels... I really don't understand why...

I just create basically a Paint Dc to display a graph with X and Y orientation. In Phoenix the Y axis is totally flattened and the basic legend associated is unreadable !... This also appeared with `wxpython` classic in windows XP, but works perfectly with `wxpython` classic in windows 7...

Here is a piece of my `OnPaint` method :

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    self.dc.Clear()

    self.dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#ffffff', wx.TRANSPARENT))
    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen((100,100,100),style=wx.SOLID))
    self.dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 210, 30)

    if self.Cadre_situation == 1:
        self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#FF0000'))
        self.dc.DrawRectangle(460, 528, 330, 80)

    self.dc.SetDeviceOrigin(330, 178)
    self.dc.SetAxisOrientation(True, True)
    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#4169E1'))
    # font = self.dc.GetFont()
    font = wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    font.SetPointSize(8.5)
    self.dc.SetFont(font)
    self.dc.DrawLine(1, 1, 530, 1)
    self.dc.DrawLine(1, 1, 1, 120)

    Increment = 0
    for i in range(0, 140, 20):
        self.dc.DrawText(str(self.Max_Echelle / 6 * Increment) + ' m3/sec', -75, i+10)
        self.dc.DrawLine(2, i, -5, i)
        Increment += 1

    for i in range(140, 590, 150):
        self.dc.DrawLine(i+5, 7, i+5, -7)
        self.dc.DrawLine(1, 7, 1, -7)
    for i in range(4):
        self.dc.DrawText(self.times[i], i*150-40, -12)

    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#4169E1'))
    for i in range(10, 310, 10):
        self.dc.DrawSpline(self.data)

    self.dc.DrawLine(1 + 2 * self.Nombre_de_reculs, 1, 1 + 2 * self.Nombre_de_reculs, 120)

    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#FF00FF'))
    for i in range(10, 310, 10):
        self.dc.DrawSpline(self.discharge_gaul)

    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#4169E1'))
    self.dc.SetDeviceOrigin(860, 178)
    self.dc.DrawLine(1, 1, 1, 120)
    for i in range(0, 121, 20):
        self.dc.DrawText(str((i)/20) + ' m', 10, i+10)
        self.dc.DrawLine(2, i, -5, i)
    event.Skip()
```

The problem seems to be in the axis orientation, when we want to draw a simple graph into a device context :

```
self.dc.SetAxisOrientation(True, True)
```

Indeed, when I put the above formulation, the Y orientation doesn't work properly (still displaying from top to bottom for Y orientation, and size of drawings are divided by something like 100!), but if I'm trying to put "True, False", or even "False, False" in the arguments, the display works in proper proportions but the graph is upside down...

Is there any changes for setting the axis orientation in the new Phoenix version ? My graph simply displays curves from basic numbers into a text file.